# GSON: Not calling my Deserializer

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I made a Deserializer in my project however this it is not being called

I am using Retrofit 2.0 with GSON and this is one my API calls

```
@GET(UrlConstants.GET_EVENT_COMMENTS)
    Call<BaseResponseObject<EventCommentsResponseObject<ItemsResponseObject<EventComment>>>> getEventComments
```

So my backend JSON data always starts as this

1. Data (object)
2. Comments (object) or another name like Foods so I might also have a  FoodResponseObject
3. Items (array)

Number 3 is an array of another kind of object in this case its EventComment which is what I want to deserialize

**Class declaration of EventComment deserialiser**

I will only show this to not clutter the post since the problem is the fact that the deserialiser is not being called

```
public class CommentDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<EventComment> {
```

Registering it on my singleton GSON instance.

```
 gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
                    .registerTypeAdapter(EventComment.class, new CommentDeserializer())
                    .create();
```

**The response objects**

Here is the what the response objects look like (as seen in the Retrofit API call declaration)

Note I use this to avoid duplicate code to serialize / deserialize the common parts of the JSON

```
public class BaseResponseObject<T> {

    @SerializedName("data")
    private T data;
```

--

```
public class EventCommentsResponseObject<T> {
    @SerializedName("comments")
    private T commentsData;
```

I am not really happy with the above because for other data I have to create another class to map the JSON

And then finally the items response object

```
public class ItemsResponseObject<T> {
    @SerializedName("items")
    private ArrayList<T> mItems;
```

This is to represent a JSON array of some data. In this case the type that is passed in is EventComment.

**Here is an example my JSON data**

```
{
  "data": {
    "comments": {
      "items": [
        {
          "id": 404,
          "body": "hi",
          "updated_at": 1445174795,
          "self": {
            "href": "http://test/exmaple/404"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 244,
          "body": "cool",
          "updated_at": 1445674795,
          "self": {
            "href": "http://test/exmaple/405"
          },

        }
      ],

    }
  }
}
```

**My Retrofit Builder**

```
  retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BuildConstants.BASE_URL)
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(getGson()))
                    .build();
```

Comment: it is not called because of a mismatch between the first parameter of  registerTypeAdapter  and the return value of your retrofit getEventComments

Comment: @Blackbelt If I change it to full type, would GSON not deserialize the common parts anymore i.e. data, comments, items. I only would like to deserialize from point of each item in the JSON array?

Comment: What if you create a new `BaseResponseObject` which doesn't use generics?

Comment: well you could give a try and debug what the deserializer will parse

Answer (score 0):

You creating new gson that knows about your deserializer, but retrofit library doesn't know anything about your new Gson object.
So u should call setCoverter() when creating RestAdapter:

```
new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(API.ENDPOINT)
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(yourgson))
            .build()
            .create(API.class);
```

Comment: Hi, so sorry, I forgot to mention that I did that already. Please check my edit. Note I use Retrofit 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Sorry people, it turns out the problem was in my call (which I did not show :( )
I had switched per page and page query params together so it was actually getting page 10 which had no data hence the deserializer was not called.

When I fixed it, the code I posted worked fine and the data is deserialized.